# Running *.jar files with Java 7 Runtime

Tags: java, openjdk, jar

When I run the `*.jar` file my Ubuntu pops up an error message with

> The file /... is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.

Though when I right clicked the `*.jar` file and got to its Properties > Open With, the Default Application to open this kind of file was already set to OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You have to give it the executable bit to run it, or use `java filename.jar` to execute it (replace filename accordingly)

Answer (score 5):

1) Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

2) `cd` into the directory containing the Jar file

3) `sudo chmod +x yourfile.jar` (Replace filename)

4) `java -jar yourfile.jar` (Replace filename)

Answer (score 3):

Open the properties again, select the tab "Permissions" and mark the checkbox "Allow executing file as program".

[image: file properties - Permissions tab]